# Is it possible to use a passed parameter several times in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am new to Laravel and I'm developing an application. I'm trying to fetch the data from a database, which works fine, and print them on a screen using a passed parameter to blade, this also works fine. However, when I want to use the same passed parameter for several times, I get the following error:

Attempt to read property "id" on bool

Here are the code snippets that I use on the application:

```
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    function getUserInfo(){
        $user_id = Auth::id();
        $beverage_list = Beverages::get();
        $places = Place::get();
         return view('profile',['list'=> $beverage_list, "places"=>$places]);

     }
}
```

I want to use the following part twice on blade.php. There is no problem when I use it once though.

```
<div class="col">
     <select name="beverage9" id="beverage9">
         <option value="">Choose your 9 o'clock beverage</option>
               @foreach($list as $list)
                 <option value="{{$list->id}}">{{$list->beverage_name}}</option>
                @endforeach
      </select>

</div>
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: since it's a collection, you might want to call it `$lists` (`return view('profile',['lists'=> $beverage_list, "places"=>$places]);`) and so in the view you will have `@foreach($lists as $list)` and it should work fine

Comment: You overwrote the $list variable in your foreach that would easily be solved by naming the second $list as $listItem
Or naming the first $list as $lists (although you'd have to pass it as ['lists' => to your blade view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return this way,

```
return view('profile',['lists'=> $beverage_list, "places"=>$places]);
```

Then in the view,

```
@foreach($lists as $list)
```